# PHP & SQL: fetch_assoc / while loop goes infinite when displaying data

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to connect to my database (it is working) and I want to select all data within the table "users". When I am displaying data, while loop with the `fetch_assoc()` never finishes. I don't understand why this is happening.

Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My first project!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $password = "";
    $db = "mydb";

    $connection = new mysqli($servername, $user, $password, $db);

    if($connection->connect_error) {
        die("Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten: $connection->connect_error");
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
    $result = $connection->query($sql);
    $resultArray = $result->fetch_assoc();

    if($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($i = $resultArray) {
            echo "ID: " . $i["id"] . "<br>Name: " . $i["username"];
        }
    } 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

If I try this version, it is working - so I don't understand why "my version" isn't. I just tried to adapt it a bit.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My first project!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $password = "";
    $db = "mydb";

    $connection = new mysqli($servername, $user, $password, $db);

    if($connection->connect_error) {
        die("Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten: $connection->connect_error");
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
    $result = $connection->query($sql);

    if($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($i = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "ID: " . $i["id"] . "<br>Name: " . $i["username"];
        }
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `while($i = $result->fetch_assoc())` calls `fetch_assoc` on every loop iteration. Your version only calls it once.

Comment: For my understanding: The first version is not working because fetch_assoc() is not in a while-loop, so that is the reason why I only get one row and it is never changing, while in the second version the fetch_assoc() is included in the loop, thats why it is giving me every row until there is no row? Thanks in advance, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right here is where you're causing an infinite loop:

```
while($i = $resultArray) {
```

This will cause the code to simply read `$resultArray` into `$i` (the first row of data returned by `fetch_assoc`) over and over again. `$resultArray` never changes and neither does `$i`, so the expression will never evaluate to `false`.

You need to be aware that when you do:

```
$resultArray = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

You are just getting a single row of data from the database - you will not be able to get multiple rows from the database with `$resultArray`.

Hence the second version is correct:

```
while($i = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
```

Answer (score 1):

In your version, you just fetched one row from the database. In the second snippet, each iteration of the loop fetches another row from the database, until the cursor is exhausted and `NULL` is returned.